# Spring Kafka infinite retry loop

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am experimenting an infinite loop on the kafka retries, in case of an exception, even if I configured a backoff strategy. Please help me understand what's going wrong in the configuration. The producer is just sending numbers from 1 to 30 in a TestMessage object correctly serialized and deserialized.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory, KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate);

        FixedBackOff fixedBackOff = new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2L);
        DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer, fixedBackOff);

        errorHandler.addRetryableExceptions(RetryableException.class);
        errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(NonRetryableException.class);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory(@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers) {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, TestMessageDeserializer.class);
        config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

Listener:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageComponentHandler {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @KafkaListener(
            id = "messageComponentConsumerClient",
            topics = "message.dispatched",
            groupId = "message.dispatched.group",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void pull(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) Integer partition, @Payload TestMessage testMessage) {
        log.info("Pulled message with id: {} and content: {} | Partition {}", testMessage.getId(), testMessage.getContent(), partition);

        if(testMessage.getId() % 6 == 0) {
            throw new RetryableException("Retryable Exception", new Exception());
        }


    }
}
```

Edit:

adding some logs

```
2024-02-21T16:09:02.434+01:00  INFO 25848 --- [merClient-0-C-1] c.c.c.handler.MessageComponentHandler    : Pulled message with id: 6 and content: Content to send | Partition 0
2024-02-21T16:09:03.526+01:00  INFO 25848 --- [merClient-0-C-1] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-message.dispatched.group-1, groupId=message.dispatched.group] Seeking to offset 36 for partition message.dispatched-0
2024-02-21T16:09:03.526+01:00 ERROR 25848 --- [merClient-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:208) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleRemaining(DefaultErrorHandler.java:168) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2884) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$56(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2755) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2742) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2595) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2481) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2123) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1442) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.consumer.cons.handler.MessageComponentHandler.pull(java.lang.Integer,com.consumer.cons.message.TestMessage)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2917) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2862) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2826) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$56(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2744) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:392) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2848) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: com.consumer.cons.exception.RetryableException: Retryable Exception
    at com.consumer.cons.handler.MessageComponentHandler.pull(MessageComponentHandler.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:376) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2848) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: null
```

Comment: Can you share the logs that you're having? And any useful stack trace?

Comment: I've posted the stacktrace and few logging